# add products to WordPress site automatically

Tags: plugins, sql

i have a products sql database table from none WordPress old site with names description and category fields but the category has only id from category table and i have to move all these products and there categories to the new WordPress site  database  , i have tried to use the plugin Product CSV Importer and Exporter  but the category field should be written by name not id .
I am still a beginner any other ideas how to start?

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSV file in Excel, use "find and replace" and change the each category id for the Category name you want. Then upload the CSV file again in the new Word Press.

Comment: sounds a good idea i will give it a try  thnx